# Web3 Solidity events do not work any more in Chrome?

Tags: web3js, metamask, events

**Ok, it seems like this issue is only present in chrome browser**
I am working with

> Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on
>   Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Actually I had some good running code, but since yesterday if I want to check the contract event log, I simply get no callback.
I'm not sure if I missed an update or did something stupid...
I tested everything on mainnet and rinkby

Now, I replicated everything with minimal running code. You can also check out [this git repo](https://github.com/kn1g/web3EventTest).

To run everything you need MetaMask isntalled:

1. Deploy to your fav Ethereum net (Mainnet, Testnet, private RPC,...)
2. Enter the contract address in the app.js file (on Rinkby the contract address is `0xd5c138d1c289a417fba456b4f8db0e88573e556b` - if no troll destroyed the contract)
3. Simply serve the files with your favorite node server (http-server, express, ...)

I am not able to check the event log of the contract any more. Maybe the MetaMask provider has some issues or maybe I'm just too stupid :/

**Solidity contract:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;


contract test {


uint256 public counter = 0;

event testEvent(address indexed _sender, uint256 _value, uint256 _counter);


function test() public{
    counter += 1;

}

function() public payable {
    raiseCounter();
}

function raiseCounter() public payable{
    testEvent(msg.sender, msg.value, counter);
    counter += 1;
}

function destroy() public{
    selfdestruct(msg.sender);
}
}
```

**Frontend js:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {


  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      window.web3   = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      startApp();
    } else {
      console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }
  });


function startApp(){
  console.log("start App");

  var contractABI = web3.eth.contract(
          [
        {
          "constant": true,
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "counter",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "name": "",
              "type": "uint256"
            }
          ],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "constant": false,
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "destroy",
          "outputs": [],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "constant": false,
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "raiseCounter",
          "outputs": [],
          "payable": true,
          "stateMutability": "payable",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "constructor"
        },
        {
          "payable": true,
          "stateMutability": "payable",
          "type": "fallback"
        },
        {
          "anonymous": false,
          "inputs": [
            {
              "indexed": true,
              "name": "_sender",
              "type": "address"
            },
            {
              "indexed": false,
              "name": "_value",
              "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
              "indexed": false,
              "name": "_counter",
              "type": "uint256"
            }
          ],
          "name": "testEvent",
          "type": "event"
        }
      ]
    );

  var contractAddress    = 'ENTER DEPLOYED ADDRESS HERE';
  var Contract = contractABI.at(contractAddress);

  var userAcc = returnAccount();
  if(userAcc != null) checkBlockNo(Contract);

  getAllValues(Contract);
  addListeners(Contract);

} 

function returnAccount(err, accounts){
  if (err != null) {
    console.error("An error occurred: "+err); 
    return null;
  } else if (web3.eth.accounts[0] == undefined) {
    return null;
  } else {
    console.log("Account: " + web3.eth.accounts[0]);
    return web3.eth.accounts[0];
  }
}

function checkBlockNo(_Contract){ 

  var filter = web3.eth.filter('latest');

  filter.watch(function(_err, _resp){
    if(_err != null){
    }else{
      var block = web3.eth.getBlockNumber(returnBlockNumber); 
      console.log(block);
    }
  });
}

function getAllValues(_Contract){

  document.getElementById('getAllValues_btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("========= CONTRACT INFO ==========");

    web3.eth.getBalance(_Contract.address,(_err, _resp) => {
      if(_err!=null){
        console.log(_err);
      }else{
        console.log("Balance: "+ web3.fromWei(_resp,'ether').toString(10));
      }
    }); 

    _Contract.counter((_err, _resp) => {
      if(_err!=null){
        console.log(_err);
      }else{
        console.log("Counter: "+_resp);
      }
    }); 
  });
}

function addListeners(_Contract){

  console.log("Adding FunctionListeners");

  document.getElementById('FunctionBtn_RaiseCounter').addEventListener("click", function() {

    _Contract.raiseCounter.sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: 0}, (_err, _resp) => {
      if(_err!=null){
        console.log(_err);
      }else{
        console.log(_resp);
      }
    }); 

  });

console.log("Adding EventListeners");

document.getElementById('EventBtn_TestEvents').addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Start query...");
  _Contract.testEvent({},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}).get((error,events) =>{
    if(error!=null){
      console.log(error);
    }else{
      console.log(events);
      if(events[0] != undefined){
        events.forEach(function(_item, _index){
          console.log("======= TestEvent =======");
          console.log("Sender: "  + _item.args._sender.toString());
          console.log("Amount: "  + web3.fromWei(_item.args._amount,'ether').toString(10));
          console.log("Counter: " + _item.args._counter.toString());
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

}
```

**Frontend HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><button id="getAllValues_btn" class="btns">Get all values</button></p>
    <p><button id="FunctionBtn_RaiseCounter" class="btns">Raise Counter</button></p>
    <p><button id="EventBtn_TestEvents" class="btns">Check Event</button></p>
    <p><button id="Destroy_btn" class="btns">Destroy!</button></p> 
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry for bothering everyone. But if you have trouble and the browser does not return any events without error msg - but everything else. Go and reset everything. I reset my browser and MetaMask. Working fine again -.-